# Modifying Code to Copy Multiple Columns and Handle Merged Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I found the following code, which has given me the first column of multiple files and placed them all into a single workbook.  My question is:  How do I tell this macro to give me multiple columns instead, and place them in a single workbook?  As well, rather than copy all of each file this macro seems to stop part way through, possibly because there are merged cells or additional white spaces.  I am wondering if there is an easy way to modify it so that it goes to the bottom of the document with certainty.  All documents have the same format.

```
 Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
         "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long

    Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
         SetCurrentDirectoryA szPath
     End Sub

    Sub Combine_Workbooks_Select_Files()
         Dim MyPath As String
         Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
         Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
         Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
         Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
         Dim SaveDriveDir As String
         Dim FName As Variant

        With Application
             CalcMode = .Calculation
             .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
             .ScreenUpdating = False
             .EnableEvents = False
         End With

        SaveDriveDir = CurDir
         ChDirNet "C:\"

        FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                                             MultiSelect:=True)
         If IsArray(FName) Then
             Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
             rnum = 1
             For Fnum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
                 Set mybook = Nothing
                 On Error Resume Next
                 Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(Fnum))
                 On Error GoTo 0
                 If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                     On Error Resume Next
                     With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                         Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:A25")
                     End With
                     If Err.Number > 0 Then
                         Err.Clear
                         Set sourceRange = Nothing
                     Else
             If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                             Set sourceRange = Nothing
                         End If
                     End If
                     On Error GoTo 0

                    If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                        SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                        If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                             MsgBox "Not enough rows in the sheet. "
                             BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                             mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                             GoTo ExitTheSub
                         Else
                             Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)
                             With sourceRange
                                 Set destrange = destrange. _
                                                 Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                             End With
                             destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                            rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                         End If
                     End If
                     mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                 End If
             Next Fnum
             BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
         End If
    ExitTheSub:
         With Application
             .ScreenUpdating = True
             .EnableEvents = True
             .Calculation = CalcMode
         End With
         ChDirNet SaveDriveDir
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided uses the variable `sourceRange` to determine which range to work with. The reason you are seeing only part of your columns copied is because `sourceRange` is hardcoded to range `A1:A25`.

So if you want the code to work with multiple columns and go to then end of the sheet, you need to change the code where `sourceRange` is set. Something like this should work:

```
'Put these declarations at the top with the others
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
```

Replace the `Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:A25")` code with the following:

```
'Use the headers to determine the last column
lastCol = .Rows("1:1").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

'Find the last row in column A
lastRow = .Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Set sourceRange using the lastRow and lastCol variables
Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
```

---

**Edit**

`searchdirection:=xlPrevious` means that the `Find` method searches columns from right to left (or rows from bottom to top). The above code searches `xlPrevious` until it finds any value (using the `*` wildcard).

If your headers are merged, the `Find` method will return the left-most column as the last used column instead of the actual last used column. For example, if `I1` and `J1` are merged, the above code will return column `I` as the last used column.

To work around this, we can work with the `MergeArea` property of the `Range` object:

```
If Rows("1:1").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).MergeArea.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    lastCol = Rows("1:1").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column + _
        Rows("1:1").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
Else: lastCol = Rows("1:1").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column 
End If
```

In the above example, we check if the last used column found is part of a merged area (if the columns count is greater than 1), and if it is, we find the last column like before, but then we count the columns in the merged area and add those columns to the last column.

Replace the `lastCol =` line in your code with the above example and you should be able to find the last column even with merged columns.

Comment: Thanks so much, it always seems so much clearer in hindsight.  I'll try out those changes.  It does seem to produce all the rows but it's still missing additional columns of information, unfortunately.  Is it possible that it is finding white space and stopping?